# How to backup and restore deployment application in glassfish

Tags: glassfish

I want to upgrade a new version of the application that already running on my glassfish server contain domain with many applications. Before deploying new version, I have to backup the running application so I could restore it when having something wrong. I've found some ways to solve:

1. Save the application directory, save the domain.xml.  When having problem, I will copy these files again to server. So could I re-deploy application by using this way?
2. Backup & restore domain that have the application. um.. I just only want to upgrade an application.

Any help?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish has built-in support of **application versioning**, which is very convenient for upgrade-revert scenarios. It is possible to deploy a new version of the application without removing the old version. You may later revert to the previous version via glassfish console or asadmin utility. Glassfish even supports **rolling upgrades** - multiple versions of application run simultaneously, new sessions are routed to new version, living sessions are served by old version until none exists and older version is turned off. In this way, users would not experience any down time.

Have a look into the Glassfish documentation on application versioning - Chapter [Module and Application Versions](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf).

In short, restrictions when using glassfish versioning:

- you must assign a version tag by naming your deployment with version suffix (only new versions need tag, current version can stay untagged)
- you must remember which version is the previous one, as more than 2 versions can be deployed (in your case this will be the one without version tag)
- remember to backup database and other external resources shared by all versions of the app

I believe that you do not need to back up anything except for the old application archive (WAR, EAR), as with usual deployment, you can always undeploy new version and deploy old version (a restart of the server may be required in between). Backup is necessary only if you need to amend glassfish configuration during deployment (new datasources, security, etc.)

Comment: This is the feature that I didn't know about glassfish. Many thank OndrejM

Comment: Useful guide about application versioning for someone like me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgbr_Hywawc